# Modify part of an existing registry key value

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to change the value in the registry.

In a batch file I have:

```
ECHO Changes in reg
reg import "C:\modifySip.reg"
```

and in `modifySip.reg` I have:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync]
"ServerSipUri"="User.Test@domainA.com"
```

And it works!

However, now I want to use part of the existing registry value and modify it.

I need to keep the `User.Test@` part of the URI, and replace the `domainA.com` part, with `domainB.com`.

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me, why can you not just change `domainA.com` to `domainB.com` in your reg file? Why are you using `reg import` with a `.reg` file when you could just use `reg add` instead? You don't even need to know what the existing value is, just overwrite it. Here's an example complete batch file for that: `@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync" /V "ServerSipUri" /D "User.Test@domainB.com" /F 1> NUL`.

Comment: If on the other hand, you meant to explain that you do not know what the current value of `User.Test` is, and that you want that part to remain, and just the domain to be modified, can you please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: I edited post. Hope now it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you've provided, and as mentioned in my comment, there's no need to use a `.reg` file for this task. I'd offer the following batch file solution:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "NewDomain=domainb.com"
Set "RegKey=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync"
Set "ValName=ServerSipUri"

For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%RegKey%" /V "%ValName%" 2> NUL"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=@" %%I In ("%%H") Do "%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "%RegKey%" /V "%ValName%" /D "%%I@%NewDomain%" /F 1> NUL
```

*Just modify line `4` to the actual domain string you require.*

Answer (score -1):

I used the code from Compo answer to get and add value to registry.
Changes of the string was made in that way:

```
set ServerSipUri=%ServerSipUri:domainA.com=domainB.com%
```

Thanks a lot for help.
Pablo

Comment: PabloPhones, If you've used my code, then the very least you could have done, was to acknowledge that by both commenting, and upvoting my answer. However, as you've effectively used all bar a small part of it, you should have accepted my answer. Incidentally, making the change you have, means that you're only changing to `domainB.com`, if it is currently `domainA.com`. Your question not make it clear that you only wanted to change it if it was a specific value. My answer, makes it `domainb.com` regardless of its current domain, which perfectly does what you requested.